# Contact form - Custom fields are not sending content

Tags: 8, emails

I've done a custom contact form with 2 more fields, but I can't get values of those 2 custom fields.

I modified contact.module in core to see what are coming from form submit, found my custom fields but they are empty. I just don't know why they are empty.

**Value of contact_form in contact.module:**

```
$contact_form = {"contact_form":[{"target_id":"feedback"}],"uuid":[{"value":"5470b680-99db-4d5a-8c00-ae043dce67e1"}],"langcode":[{"value":"pt-br"}],"name":[{"value":"Name"}],"mail":[{"value":"some@mail.com"}],"subject":[{"value":"Any"}],"message":[{"value":"Any message"}],"copy":[{"value":0}],"recipient":[],"field_customa":[],"field_customb":[]}
;
```

Any clues to make this contact form work?

Comment: I think the values are in a Message entity (defined in contact module). It seems as if the entity is passed straight into the parameters for the mail handler and mail system, and my guess is that the entity is being magic-method serialized/toString'd.

Comment: Not really, Message entity don't store any form fields. Message body is defined in `contact_mail()` function with this statement `$message['body'][] = (string) \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);` and before this statement I'm checking if `field_customa` and `field_customb` have any values. All other fields have their values, but the custom ones not.

Comment: Yes, but the message body is comprised of parameters coming from [MessageForm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!contact!src!MessageForm.php/class/MessageForm/8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 8 will handle custom fields on contact forms 'out-the-box', they will be rendered in the message body by contact module. If custom fields don't appear in message body, someone messed up.

In this particular case, attribute 'name' of 'input' html tags were modified, and $_POST came with a wrong schema. $_POST['field'] instead of $_POST['field'][0]['value'].

Here shows the hint:
`"message":[{"value":"Any message"}]` - Correct (field[0]['value'])
`"field_customa":[]` - Wrong (field[])